# Need to transpose 1 row of data into 1 column but multiple rows

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have 3 columns and 1 row:

```
Sequence     01         02
100001       002        004
```

But need to transpose into 2 columns and 2 rows:

```
Sequence   Family
1000001    002
1000001    004
```

However my MySQL is limited and would appreciate some help.

Following MySQL code Ive tried:

```
SELECT tracabilite AS Sequence,
(CASE WHEN MID(CodeBarre,72,3) = '002' THEN '002' ELSE NULL END) AS 'Family',
(CASE WHEN MID(CodeBarre,75,3) = '004' THEN '004' ELSE NULL END) AS 'Family'
FROM table_msg WHERE tracabilite = 10000004
GROUP BY Family;'
```

But the above code displays:

```
Sequence    Family  Family
1000001       002   002
```

Comment: I'm confused as to where that `100002` came from. Could you add a larger sample of your source table and desired output?

Comment: My bad. Copy paste.  Should be 100001

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SQL you have tried, it appears you have two (not three) columns, tracabilite and CodeBarre. It would really help if you displayed the actual row contents in its entirety. I am also still not sure what your constant values are (1000001 or 100001), but you will get the idea:

```
SELECT tracabilite AS Sequence, MID(CodeBarre,72,3) AS 'Family'
FROM table_msg WHERE tracabilite = 1000001 AND MID(CodeBarre,72,3) = '002'
UNION
SELECT tracabilite AS Sequence, MID(CodeBarre,75,3) AS 'Family'
FROM table_msg WHERE tracabilite = 1000001 AND MID(CodeBarre,75,3) = '004'
;
```

We are performing the UNION of two SELECT statements. The first SELECT statement should produce:

```
1000001 002
```

and the second SELECT statement should produce:

```
1000001 004
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.  Your code returned values as expected.  Simple when you know how.  Many thanks. :)

Comment: @StuGibson If this response answered your question, then would you mark it as such (i.e. as the accepted answer) and possibly upvote it?